# Why no compiler error for this closure function?

Tags: javascript, closures

I am reading Marijn Haverbeke's excellent book, "Eloquent JavaScript".
https://eloquentjavascript.net/

I do not understand [this example](https://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html) on closures where `number` is not defined, yet there is no error.

Is `number` a function or a parameter?

There is nothing to indicate that `number` is passed in as parameter the second time.

```
function multiplier(factor) {
  return number => number * factor;
}

let twice = multiplier(2);
console.log(twice(5));
// → 10
```

Comment: `number` is the parameter of the returned function.

Comment: it's same as  `return x => x * factor;`

Comment: Number is defined when you call `twice(5)`. Here `number` is defined as `5`. You have defined the function `twice` as `twice = function (number) {return number * 2}`

Comment: @slebetman now, I understand - thanks! So it is a function that takes multiple parameters in stages. please put your reply as an answer so I can accept it. I don't know why someone has voted to close the question - don't they want people to learn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understanding how closures work is hard enough but when the example you're looking at arbitrarily mixes a function declaration with an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) - as this one does - if you don't understand how arrow functions work it makes it more difficult to understand.

Here's a slightly easier example that doesn't use an arrow function to show what's going on.

```js
// `multipler` takes a factor as an argument
function multiplier(factor) {

  // It returns a function that - when it's called -
  // accepts a number
  return function (number) {

    // And the return from that function
    // is the factor * number
    return number * factor;
  }
}

// So we call `multipler` with a factor and assign the
// function it returns to our `twice` variable
let twice = multiplier(2);

// We can then call the function assigned
// to `twice` with a number, and the resulting
// return from that function will be factor * number
console.log(twice(5));
```

In terms of the example using that arrow function:

```js
// We pass in a factor to the `multipler`
function multiplier(factor) {
  
  // We return a function that accepts a number
  // and returns factor * number
  // (I've added parentheses around the number
  // parameter to clearly show it)
  return (number) => number * factor;
}

// So we call `multipler` with a factor and assign the
// function it returns to our `twice` variable
let twice = multiplier(2);

// We can then call the function assigned
// to `twice` with a number, and the resulting
// return from that function will be factor * number
console.log(twice(5));
```